# Cursor format for Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, cursor-theme

I have a few SVGs which I am trying to use as a cursor pointer in `Ubuntu 22.04`. In `Windows`, we can convert them into a `.cur` or `.ani` file and use Mouse Settings to use it. Is there any such way to convert an SVG or PNG to a cursor format and then add it to Ubuntu?

Thanks.

Comment: It's mostly similar ... There are `.cur` icons for each theme under `/usr/share/icons/` ... See e.g. `/usr/share/icons/Yaru/cursors/hand.cur` ... Change it for your current mouse cursor theme and it should be a matter of changing the theme to something else then changing back and it should change the cursor.

Comment: Thanks @Raffa , If I copy the whole Yaru cursor folder into `.icons` and edit the `index.theme` to say `newru`, can I change the main cursor just by replacing it with the .cur equivalent in the `newru` folder?

Comment: I haven't tried that but IIRC there is some theme `.css` file that should be the one to edit ... And it should work this way as well.

Comment: I ran `file /usr/share/icons/Yaru/cursors/hand.cur` and the output was `MS Windows cursor resource - 5 icons, 96x96, hotspot @29x16` which means it's a windows style cursor file ... and looked at this howto: https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/how-to-change-the-mouse-cursor-on-ubuntu-linux/ and it sounds reasonable and seems not complicated after all.

Comment: I can make cursor themes out of Yaru's GitHub resource. But not sure what format they are in. At the moment, I have to edit the base SVG, and then run 3 scripts even if I have to modify a single cursor. In Windows, we can make a .cur or .ani and replace any single cursor item. That is why I thought of checking which format they are in. Thanks for the research.

Comment: Probably this will help: https://github.com/charakterziffer/cursor-toolbox